# ErrorDocument 404 Not Working. Is .htaccess is blocking my 404 redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have set up cutePHP (cms) up in a directory on my server.
http://example.com/x

i have once .htaccess file in the root of my server.
http://example.com

By visiting http://example.com you are redirect to http://example.com/x - This is what i want

If i goto http://example.com/x/PageThatDoesntExist.php - It takes me back to http://example.com/x - This is acceptable, but not exactly what I want.

However, if i goto http://example.com/PageThatDoesntExist.php - It takes me to a messed up version of my site.

Why is 'ErrorDocument 404' doing it's job?

Here is my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm

# --- XBOXMADDER[ST]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tic$ http://www.example.com/x/tic [L]
# --- XBOXMADDER[ED]

# --- XBOXMAD[ST]
Options +FollowSymlinks
Redirect /index.html http://www.example.com/x/
# --- XBOXMAD[ED]

# --- CUTENEWS[ST]
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /team/show_news.php?cn_rewrite_url=$1 [L]
# --- CUTENEWS[ED]
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's becasue you are redirecting 404's to `/team/show_news.php?cn_rewrite_url` (becasue of above `!-d` and `!-f` conditions). Can you change the last rule to be more specific ?.also you don't need the second `RewriteEngine ON` line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Himal.
I will focus my attention on this part of my .htaccess file. Unfortunately I know VERY little about .htaccess and RegEx. I have done a fair bit of research into these but I'm still unable to figure out a solution. If you could provide me with a point in the right direction, I would be most thankful.

Comment: `^(.*)$` means capture all. See if you can make it more specific to the requesting URL.just like you are going with your first rule `^tic$`. Then you can rewrite them to `show_news.php` and rest of the non existing URLs would show the 404 page.You have to remove `!-d` and `!-f` lines as well.Can you provide a URL pattern that would be forwarded to `/team/show_news.php?cn_rewrite_url=` path.